# Не компилируется Hallo world на Kotlin. Кнопка Run не активна. Пробовал разные варианты написания

Tags: kotlin

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Не компилируется Hallo world на Kotlin. Кнопка Run не активна. Пробовал разные варианты написания

Comment: А что вы сделали чтобы скомпилировать его?

Answer (score 2):

Надо настроить параметры запуска в "Add Configuration" слева от запуска
[image: Добавление конфигурации запуска]

После этого нажмите на значок Kotlin рядом с первой строкой кода или на название файла и выберите в появившемся меню пункт Run '<название Вашей конфигурации>':
[image: Run]

Comment: Нет у него этого значка у main()

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался! Не там создал сам файл. Пересоздал его в папке srs main kotlin

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]